# how to create a data validation column in excel from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have a data frame like below `df`

```
SL.No  Invoice     
1       A2345
2       B1624
3       C1234
```

I need create another column `Status` with values such ['Approved',' Rejected','Partially Approved'] against each row to write into a excel file.

How can this be done using python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get what you want by using "xlsxwriter" engine. Please follow the below steps. I assumed "Invoice" is in column C. So, the output will be in Column D.

```
# Export to xlsx file
df.to_excel("c:/Error/DropDown.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter') 

#Open it with xlsxwriter
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("c:/Error/DropDown.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter') 
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

#Assign the workbook and worksheet
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

#Adding the header and Datavalidation list
worksheet.write('D1', 'Status')
worksheet.data_validation('D2', {'validate': 'list',
                                  'source': ['Approved',' Rejected','Partially Approved']})
workbook.close()
```

Document to refer: [xlsxwriter_Dropdown](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_data_validate.html?highlight=data%20validation#example-data-validation-and-drop-down-lists)